# Android getExternalStorageDirectory() behavior on all devices

Tags: android, android-sdcard, environment, android-external-storage

Do the following method on all mobile devices and all versions of Android tablet is working properly?

- All Phones example: samsung sony htc LG huawei and etc...
- API 15 +

  `if (MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(getExternalStorageState())) {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myfolder";
   }`
- String path always is return **Correctly** and always **exists** on all phones?
- It is possible that errors on some phones and versions?

Comment: Yes it can change..some of the devices such as LGE Nexus 5 or 5X dont have SD card option.In these devices it can change

Comment: @Nishith what is return `string path` on LGE nexus 5 or ... ? errors or not exists?

Comment: @Nishith: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is for external storage, not removable storage.

Comment: @Nishith nexus 5 don't have external storage?

Comment: Ya ,Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() is for external storage. But what I have observed is that in the devices which do not support SD card, they return some different path on this command. Its just an observation.

Comment: @Nishith: The specific path returned by `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` will vary for lots of reasons.

Comment: Ya , I totally agree...It was just my observation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is possible that errors on some phones and versions?

Sure. It is fairly unlikely, particularly for devices that legitimately have the Play Store and other Google proprietary apps. Devices with those apps have to pass through compatibility testing, and that testing will include testing external storage.

> String path always is return Correctly and always exists on all phones?

Your `path` will exist on approximately zero phones, as few devices will ship with a `myfolder/` directory off the root of external storage. The external storage path (`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`) should exist.

Comment: `getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myfolder".mkdirs();` always return true?

Comment: @grizzly: Never use concatenation to build a path. Use `new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "myfolder")`. `mkdirs()` returns `false` if the directory was not created, such as if the directory was already there.